# Call Nintex Workflow StartWorkflowOnListItem from client application

Tags: web-services, nintex-workflow

I'll trying to start a Nintex Workflow 2010 from outside of SharePoint. I can't seem to find any samples on how to can call this from maybe a console application. Does anybody have code samples or knows blogs that actually shows this.

Thanks,
Jimbo

Answer (score 0):

CSOM Workflows API is not supported in SharePoint 2010, but you could consume [SharePoint Workflow Web Services (SOAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981383(v=office.12).aspx) for that purpose.

Use [Workflow.StartWorkflow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcworkflow.workflow.startworkflow(v=office.12).aspx) to start a workflow on an item for the client.

### How to consume SharePoint Workflow Web Services in Visual Studio

- Create a new console application project in Visual Studio
- Right click on References and Add Service Reference
- Put in the URL to the `workflow.asmx` service on your server Example: `<web url>/_vti_bin/workflow.asmx` and specify namespace name, for example `WorkflowSvc`

In order Sharepoint Web Services to work with NTLM authentication please make the following  changes  `app.config` file.

Replace `security` section from:

```
<security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

to:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
</security>
```

The following code sample demonstrates how to start a workflow on an item:

```
var workflowClient = new WorkflowSvc.WorkflowSoapClient();
workflowClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
workflowClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

var workflowParameters = "<my:myFields " +
                                 "xml:lang=\"en-us\" " +
                                 "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                                 "xmlns:my=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD\">" +
                                 "</my:myFields>";
var listItemUrl = "http://contoso.intranet.com/Documents/Order.docx";
var wfTemplateId = new Guid("{0fd3e822-a3b1-45c1-990c-20cb9731e74f}");
var result = workflowClient.StartWorkflow(listItemUrl, wfTemplateId, XElement.Parse(workflowParameters));
```